# how to install SystemTap on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, systemtap

I am new to Ubuntu. 
I follow the instruction from  http://sourceware.org/systemtap/wiki/SystemtapOnUbuntu that is necessary to install SystemTap on Ubuntu.

I lost in Step 4.

**How can i run step 4:  ?**

Setp 4: `sudo apt-get install elfutils`, for eu-readelf Then run this script as root, whenever you install additional debug symbols

```
for file in `find /usr/lib/debug -name '*.ko' -print`
do
        buildid=`eu-readelf -n $file| grep Build.ID: | awk '{print $3}'`
        dir=`echo $buildid | cut -c1-2`
        fn=`echo $buildid | cut -c3-`
        mkdir -p /usr/lib/debug/.build-id/$dir
        ln -s $file /usr/lib/debug/.build-id/$dir/$fn
        ln -s $file /usr/lib/debug/.build-id/$dir/${fn}.debug
done
```

This makes available the module probes available and is friendly to other debug symbol savvy apps like gdb and oprofile. This convention should make it's way into Ubuntu in the near future.

Answer (score 0):

You should be more specific with your problems. "I lost in" isn't good enough on this site.

I had a problem related to permissions. If that's the case, prefix "sudo" to the lines starting with "mkdir" and "ln -s".